# ReactJS: Use const from another file

Tags: reactjs

In weights.js I have:

```
const Weights = ({ data, country, listItemUser, gear }) => {
    const newarr = [];
    data?.map(el => {
        el?.gearHiking?.map(els => {
            newarr?.push(els)
        })
    })
    const newarr2 = [];
    data?.map(el => {
        el?.foodHiking?.map(els => {
            newarr2?.push(els)
        })
    })
    const getcamper4x4wei = useMemo(() => {
        let initialValue = 0
        if (country?.label == "4x4 TOWING CAMPER") {
            const gettata = data.filter(el => el.packingLocation == "4x4" ? true : false)
            return gettata?.reduce(
                (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + Number(currentValue.Weight) * Number(currentValue.Quantity)
                , initialValue
            )
        }
    }, [data]);
}

export default Weights
```

and then I import this file in app.js as:

```
import Weights from './weights'
```

In app.js how do I access the const of getcamper4x4wei?

Comment: Given that `import Weightsfrom './weights'` isn't Javascript, and you're guaranteed to get an error for that line: fix your missing space =D

Comment: Sorry - that was a typo - have edited the question

Comment: You'll also want to actually use the real filename, not just leave things to guess at what the extension is.

Answer (score 0):

Add a return statement to your `Weight` function:

```js
return getcamper4x4wei;
```

Then, in app.js, you can access its value - but be aware that `Weight` now returns a state variable that can change at runtime, so you should use it in `useEffect`:

```js
// in app.js

useEffect(()=>console.log("Weight changed: ", Weight), [Weight]);
```

Comment: I use the return but in app.js I still get the Uncaught ReferenceError: getcamper4x4wei is not defined ... when just doing a console.log(getcamper4x4wei )

Comment: So in your app your code is different from the code you posted? In the code you posted , Weight() does not return anything, and you also don't console.log(getcamper4x4wei )

Comment: No, but I am trying to get the value of getcamper4x4wei - In app.js how do I access the const of getcamper4x4wei?