# ReactJS: How to use a const from another file

Tags: reactjs

In weights.js I have:

```
const Weights = ({ data, country, listItemUser, gear }) => {
const getdgearcamoper = useMemo(() => {
        let initialValue = 0
        if (country?.label == "ENGLAND") {
            const gettata = data.filter(el => el.packingLocation == "Resident" ? true : false)
            return gettata?.reduce(
                (previousValue, currentValue) => previousValue + Number(currentValue.Weight) * Number(currentValue.Quantity)
                , initialValue
            )
        }
}, [data]);

return (
<TextField disabled InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true, }} id="standard-basic" label="PERSON" value={getdgearcamoper?.toFixed(0)} name="campertotalinput" type="number" variant="outlined" />
)
}

export default Weights
```

Then in additem.js I import this via:

```
import Weights from './weights'
```

I am trying to use this same TextField with the value

```
{getdgearcamoper?.toFixed(0)}
```

in additem.js ... but if I try it still displays:
ReferenceError: getdgearcamoper is not defined

How can I show this const in additem.js?

Comment: You can't unless you extract `getdgearcamoper` out so that it is not part of the component. What does `additem` supposed to do and why does it need to access an attribute of a component?

Comment: OK, thank you - how do I extract that out of the component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS: Use const from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72738230/reactjs-use-const-from-another-file)

Comment: No, it does not. Because it was asked by the same person and he is still asking the same question.

Comment: If it is a must to share this function then you should move it outside of the component, as previuos comment suggest. You can jus make it as pure js function (helper or utils), for example make it as `getdgearcamoper ` function which accepts 2 arguments, `countryLabel` and `data`, since I can see that result depends only of those two. Then you can call this function independently in `Weights` and also inside `addItem`. Just declare new function in separate file and export it.

Comment: To @PaulVI, to answer that, you first have to explain what `additem` does. Because `getdgearcamoper` is depending on the props of `Weights` and you can't just extract it and make it a function and expect it to work without knowing the details.